# Getting OS error with Windows (OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application) and Linux with example code

Tags: python, windows

I received a spectrometer sensor and I was trying to run its example Python API code to start working with it. I have tested this on Linux and I got an issue with OSError: libgsl.so.0 cannot open shared files error. So now I am trying to run the same code on Windows 10 but I seem to be getting another OS error. I am running their following code which produces the error at the beginning during `#Initialization`:

```
import sys
import csv
sys.path.append("..\..\..\..\wrappers/python")

if(sys.version_info[0] < 3):
    from wrapper_python2 import *
    from wrapper_python2.core import *
    from wrapper_python2.device import *
    from wrapper_python2.color import *
    print ("**********************************************************************")
    print ("[Python-2]        Python Version : ", sys.version_info.major, "." ,sys.version_info.minor , " Detected")
    print ("**********************************************************************")
else:
    print ("**********************************************************************")
    print ("[Python-3]        Python Version : ", sys.version_info.major, "." ,sys.version_info.minor , " Detected")
    print ("**********************************************************************")
    from wrapper_python3 import *
    from wrapper_python3.core import *
    from wrapper_python3.device import *
    from wrapper_python3.color import *


#Initialization
if sys.platform == 'win32':

    initialize("..\Libs\CrystalBase.dll")
    pSpecCore      = initialize_core_api("..\Libs\CrystalCore.dll")
    pSpecDevice    = initialize_device_api("..\Libs\CrystalPort.dll")
else:
    initialize("../Libs/libCrystalBase.so")
    pSpecCore      = initialize_core_api("../Libs/libCrystalCore.so")
    pSpecDevice    = initialize_device_api("../Libs/libCrystalPort.so")

initialize_color_api(pSpecCore)


connectReturn   = connect_device(pSpecDevice)   # return total num of devices connected with system

if connectReturn > 0:

    (ret, sensorID) = get_sensor_id_device(pSpecDevice)

    create_core_object(pSpecCore)

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        csInit_Return = load_sensor_file(pSpecCore, b"..\config\sensor_" + sensorID + b".dat")
    else:
        csInit_Return = load_sensor_file(pSpecCore, b"../config/sensor_" + sensorID + b".dat")
        
    
    if(csInit_Return > 0):

        (ret, sensorID) = get_sensor_id_file(pSpecCore)

        get_sensor_parameters_from_device(pSpecDevice)

        (adcGain,adcRange) = get_sensor_parameters_from_calibration_file(pSpecCore)

        settingReturn = set_sensor_parameters_to_device(pSpecDevice,adcGain,adcRange)

        total_num_of_sensors = total_sensors_connected(pSpecDevice)

        get_capacity_sensor_data_list(pSpecCore)

        for index in range(total_num_of_sensors):

            #activate a specific device(sensor)
            activatingReturn = index_activation(pSpecDevice,index)

            #get sensor id of currently activated device(sensor)
            (ret, sensorID) = get_sensor_id_device(pSpecDevice)

            #get and set shutter speed of device(sensor)
            get_shutter_speed(pSpecDevice)
            set_shutter_speed(pSpecDevice,1)

            #get one filter output (sensor data)
            filterData = get_filter_data(pSpecDevice,20)

            #set background data
            set_background_data(pSpecCore,filterData)

            #get and set shutter speed of device(sensor)

            #get_shutter_speed(pSpecDevice)
            
            valid_filters_num = get_num_of_valid_filters(pSpecCore)
            valid_filters = get_valid_filters(pSpecCore)

            newSS = 50
            frame_avg = 20
            do_AE = True
            
            #Get shutter speed with AE
            if do_AE:
                newSS = get_optimal_shutter_speed(pSpecDevice,valid_filters_num,valid_filters)

            set_shutter_speed(pSpecDevice,newSS)

            #convert shutter speed to exposure time (ms) for your reference
            ss_to_exposure_time(pSpecDevice,5,newSS)

            filterData = get_filter_data(pSpecDevice,frame_avg)

            specSize = get_spectrum_length(pSpecCore)

            (ret, specData,wavelengthdata) = calculate_spectrum(pSpecCore,filterData,newSS)

            (Start_Wavelength, End_Wavelength, Interval_Wavelength) = get_wavelength_information(pSpecCore)

            if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
                fileName = (r"SpecrtumData2_" + sensorID + ".csv");
                data = []
                for i in range(get_spectrum_length(pSpecCore)):
                    data.append(str(specData[i]).split(","))

                with open(fileName, "wb") as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                    for line in data:
                        writer.writerow(line)
                csv_file.close()
            else:
                fileName = (b"SpecrtumData3_" + sensorID + b".csv");
                data = []
                for i in range(get_spectrum_length(pSpecCore)):
                    data.append(str(specData[i]).split(","))

                with open(fileName, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                    for line in data:
                        filewriter.writerow(line)
                csvfile.close()
    else:
        print ("**********************************************************************")
        print ("[PrismError] Sensor Calibration File Not Present in Config Foler. Please copy Sensor Calibration File in Config file and execute again.")
        print ("**********************************************************************")
else:
    print ("**********************************************************************")
    print ("[PrismError]Device Not Connected. Please connect Device and try again.")
    print ("**********************************************************************")
close_color_api(pSpecCore)
close_core_object(pSpecCore)
disconnect_device(pSpecDevice)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error and I am perplexed about how I go about resolving it for my specific case.

```
**********************************************************************
[Python-3]        Python Version :  3 . 8  Detected
**********************************************************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jeff\Downloads\New folder\NSP32_SDK_1_7_windows.tar\nanoLambda\NSP32_SDK\examples\python\win32\example_wrapper_python\example_wrapper_python_color.py", line 24, in <module>
    initialize("..\Libs\CrystalBase.dll")
  File "../../../../wrappers/python\wrapper_python3\initialize.py", line 10, in initialize
    ctypes.CDLL("..\Libs\pthreadVC2.dll")
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\miniconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

This is the following directory structure for this application
[image]

Comment: Ensure that the architecture of the DLL you are trying to load (either x86 or x86-64, "32" or "64-bit") matches the architecture of your Python installation.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix it. It is not working